# Who handles a event created by a component in java

Tags: java, swing, button, components

I have read that that a event  created by a component(like a button) is handled by a action listener(for a button) but one of my teacher says that every event is handled by the operating system so I am confused to as who actually handles the event, is it the operating system or does java do that work.

Comment: You look at the top level of the event stack - your component. The OS will generate the low level event, which is then converted and added to the Event Dispatching Thread, which is then processed by your component, which is finally delivered to your listeners

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the two instances of the word `handle` here mean quite different things.

Your code handles events that are *raised*. So imagine the button says "Oh I've been clicked!" and you go "Right, I'll *handle* it!" and you do this by doing something like this:

```
button.addActionListener(e -> {...});
```

The OS handles *the raising of events*. Your mouse pointer is not part of your program, right? So the OS will detect where your mouse pointer is when a "The left mouse button has been clicked" signal is sent to the OS. The OS will say "The mouse pointer is located at this position on the screen, and there is a button there. That means that the button should be clicked. Hey! that button over there! The user clicked on you at (someX, someY)!". And then the `JButton` class will first try to animate a click animation and raise the "action performed" event.

Comment: Thank you for the well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Certain types of `events` occur as a direct result of user input. When the user types a key or moves the mouse, for example, a `KeyEvent` or `MouseEvent` is generated. Similarly, when the user resizes a window or transfers keyboard focus to a new component, a `FocusEvent` or `ComponentEvent` is generated. These types of events represent event notifications generated by the underlying native windowing system or **operating system**. Other types of events, such as `ActionEvent` and `PopupMenuEvent`, **do not originate in the native windowing system**. Instead, these events are generated directly by `AWT` and `Swing` components

Comment: So a Action Event is handled by AWT itself and the operating system is not involved??

Comment: @Ayush.S An event is generated by the `Button`, but the OS will handle the even lower-level stuff like telling the button that it has been clicked.

Comment: @Sweeper so a action event will be handled by java itself but the other events like mouse clicks and mouse position will be handled by the operating system.

Comment: @Ayush.S You can kind of think of it like that. The OS is always lower level. The more abstract ideas, like "action performed" are all JWT and Swing's work.

Comment: Oh that explained everything.